# Trying to pull a list of remote applications using WMIC and "Name like '%wildcard%'"

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

```
@echo off

set /p pcname= Computer Name? 
set /p product= What software are you looking for? 

wmic /node:%pcname% product where "Name like '%product%'" get Name, Version
pause
```

---

after this runs I get "no instances available" I can get this to work with specific applications i.e. "Name like 'Microsoft'" get name, version 
but when I try to run a wildcard for user input I get nothing.

Comment: `%product%` is the contents of the variable. If you want to surround that in percent signs for wildcarding purposes, add them: `%%product%%`. Are you sure you wouldn't rather use PowerShell instead? :-P

Comment: Probbly should be using PS lol but adding a second set of % doesnt work with a wildcard. "Name like '%%product%%'" get name, version Gives the same output

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!!

```
@echo off
:start
set /p pcname= Computer Name? 
set /p product= What software are you looking for? 

wmic /node:%pcname% product where "Name like '%%%product%%%'" get Name, Version
pause
goto start
```